# Graph with two strongly connected components

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let there be two strongly connected components in directed graph $G$. It is known that the basis of graph $G$ is connected and it does not have bridges. Prove that there exists such edge that if we change its direction, then graph $G$ will become strongly connected.

I did my best to translate the problem from Swedish to English so let me know if the problem is not clear enough. We just started learning directed graphs so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the basis of $G$ the underlying undirected graph?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. I did not know that it had its own term :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that the basis of $G$ is the underlying undirected graph.  That is, $G$ with the orientation of the edges removed. Say the two strongly connected components are $S$ and $T$.  Since the basis is connected there must be an edge joining a vertex in $S$ and a vertex in $T$.  WLOG we may say $e=st,$ where $s\in S,t\in T$.  If $e$ were the only edge between $S$ and $T$ it would be a bridge in the basis, so there is another such edge $f$.  If $f=\tau\sigma,\tau\in T,\sigma\in S$, then $G$ is strongly connected, so $f$ also goes from $S$ to $T$.  Changing the direction of either $e$ or $f$ would make $G$ strongly connected.